# The features importance from scikit -learn pipeline (SVC)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I have the following pipelines, I want to get the features wights with respect to each class. I have three classes ('Fiction','None-fiction','None'). The classifier that I use is `SVC`.

```
Book_contents= Pipeline([('selector', ItemSelector(key='Book')),
                         ('tfidf',CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',
                                                  binary=True,
                                                  ngram_range=(1,1))),
                        ])

Author_description= Pipeline([('selector', ItemSelector(key='Description')),
                              ('tfidf', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',
                                                        binary=True,
                                                        ngram_range=(1,1))),
                             ])

ppl = Pipeline([('feats', FeatureUnion([('Contents',Book_contents),
                                        ('Desc',Author_description)])),
                ('clf', SVC(kernel='linear',class_weight='balanced'))
               ])

model = ppl.fit(training_data, Y_train)
```

I have tried eli5 but I got error of mismatch between feature name and classifier.

```
f1=model.named_steps['feats'].transformer_list[0][1].named_steps['tfidf'].get_feature_names()
f2=model.named_steps['feats'].transformer_list[1][1].named_steps['tfidf'].get_feature_names()
    list_features=f1
list_features.append(f2)
explain_weights.explain_linear_classifier_weights(model.named_steps['clf'], 
                                              vec=None, top=20, 
                                              target_names=ppl.classes_, 
                                              feature_names=list_features)
```

I got this error:

> feature_names has a wrong length: expected=47783, got=10528

How to get the rank of features wights with respect to each class? is their a way to do that without eli5?

Comment: Please explain what you are doing in this code:                                               `feature_names=model.named_steps['feats'].transformer_list[0][1].named_steps['tfidf'].get_feature_names()`?

Comment: Hi @VivekKumar this code to access the steps from the pipeline in-order to get the features but I am not sure if this is the accurate way to do it

Comment: Thats why I asked. You only accessed the features from first part of FeatureUnion, but not from second

Comment: thank you for pointing that out @VivekKumar but even after adding each features I still can not access the wights. Is there another way other than eli5. something with coef_ maybe ?

Comment: How are you doing that

Comment: I just edited the post with the required details. Hope it is clear now

Answer (score 2):

You are doing everything correct except for this line:

```
list_features.append(f2)
```

Here you append the whole `f2` list as an element to `f1` list. This is not what you want.

You want to add all the elements of f2 to f1. For that you need to use `extend`. Just do this:

```
list_features.extend(f2)
```

See this question for more details:

- [Difference between append vs. extend list methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252703/3374996)

In addition to that, I think the way you call `explain_weights.explain_linear_classifier_weights` is wrong. You just need to call `explain_weights(...)` and it will automatically internally call the `explain_linear_classifier_weights`.

Comment: He could also do `list_features += f2`